# how to upload two different files (image and txt file) in laravel

Tags: laravel

hi guys i am in strange situation :(
I have an update view where i have two fields of upload file 
1. image 
2. text file 
in image section get image that's already save in db. but cv is not save in db when i upload cv and not image it gives me error of

**Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on null**
why is this happens.

**here is my view**

```
<form class="checkout woocommerce-checkout" method="post" class="form-horizontal"
      action="{{Route('studentUpdateProfile')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-lg-offset-3 col-md-offset-3 col-sm-offset-3">
        <div class="mj_mainheading mj_toppadder50 mj_bottompadder55">
            <h1 style="font-size:35px;"> P<span style="font-size:28px;">ersonal</span> i<span style="font-size:28px;">formation</span>
            </h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group" style="width: 50%; ">
        <img id="blah" src="{{ asset("uploads/images/$user->image") }}" alt="User Image" height="150"/>
        <br><br>
        <input type='file' id="image" name="image" value="image"/>

    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mj_bottompadder20">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label>Select C.V
            </label>
            <input type='file' id="cv" name="cv" value="cv"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

in my controller

```
public function updateUserProfile(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [


        'cv' => 'max:2048',
    ]);

   $image = $request->file('image');

    $upload = 'uploads/images';
    $filename = $image->getClientOriginalName();
     $image->move($upload, $filename);

    $file = $request->file('cv');
    $upload = 'uploads/cv';
    $cv = $file->getClientOriginalName();
    $file->move($upload, $cv);

        $user = Auth::User();

        $user->accountType = $request->accountType;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->userName = $request->userName;
        $user->gender = $request->gender;
        $user->dob = $request->dob;
        $user->country = $request->country;
        $user->city = $request->city;
        $user->mobileNo = $request->mobileNo;
        $user->cnic = $request->cnic;
        $user->address = $request->address;
        $user->degreeLevel = $request->degreeLevel;
        $user->degreeTitle = $request->degreeTitle;
        $user->institution = $request->institution;
        $user->degreeCountry = $request->degreeCountry;
        $user->degreeCity = $request->degreeCity;
        $user->experience = $request->experience;
        $user->workExperience = $request->workExperience;
        $user->industry = $request->industry;
        $user->acedCountry = $request->acedCountry;
        $user->image = $filename;
        $user->cv = $cv;
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->back();
    }
}
```

Comment: <form class="checkout woocommerce-checkout"  method="post" class="form-horizontal" action="{{Route('studentUpdateProfile')}}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

Comment: getClientOriginalName is a method available to the UploadedFile class. To help debug, you should dump the values of the request and see what's really being set in the image property. `dd($request->all());`. Make sure you  have the proper enctype (multipart/form-data) set on the form as well.